# How should i handle my co-worker?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, work-life-balance

I work in the medical field and i need some advice.

Does a coworker have the right to tell you which patient to room? Tell you to hurry up? Even though the doctor isn't behind with his schedule?

How can i respond?

Comment: Does "pt" mean patient?

Comment: if they have seniority, they might not have the official capacity to tell you who goes into which room, but it is best if you heed their advice especially if it makes sense. For instance if he/she is asking you to place a patient with a broken bone to room near the x-ray machine, why not ? On the other hand, they might be playing for a supervisory role and are expecting to be promoted by stepping over others, barking orders, which is not cool

Comment: Just a few minutes ago you had a long post on this same thing.   Don't delete and re-post.  And use whole words and capital I.

Comment: VTC.  This is a rant.

Comment: Thank you melBurslan for your response. I deleted my previous post due to some negative responses due to my grammar. So i thought id keep it short and simple and straight to the point.

Comment: We can't know who has what responsibilities and authority in your specific organization.  Ask your manager.

Comment: @Veronica in the future please edit the post instead of deleting and reposting.  (There's an "edit" link under the question.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat my prior comment:

If she is the office manager, she has that authority.

If she has been given that authority by the office manager -- you did say she was assigned to train you -- she has that authority.

If neither of these is true, then find the office manager and politely ask for guidance on how to handle this. You said you were relatively new to the office; she may know things you don't about how that office works.